# How to get sonarqube code coverage on tests running on wildfly server

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, wildfly-9, sonarqube-scan

I'm running my integration tests on wildfly server. 1st we deploy our artifact and then another test project will consume the API of deployed project and do complete integration testing. Is there a way to report the code coverage sonarqube ?

Comment: Just curious, isn't that the reason why you have Arquillian suite for. If it's simple RESTEasy,it has it's own mocks and setup.

Comment: The project is quite complex. And runs though so many layers to produce results. So mocking parts will consume lot of time. Thats why we need to run integration tests as in the real system as a whole.

Comment: Arquillian is an intergration test-suite as far as I have read. Anyhow, even I have run basic testing only. Can you describe a bit more what are you trying to mock an EJB, MDB or REST component?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your IT suite produces reports. You simply need to wait to do the analysis until after the IT is done, then feed the resulting reports into the analysis.